# Making an image responsive (re-size with browser)

Tags: html, css, image, browser, rescale

i'm attempting to make an image I have positioned in the center of the page, responsive (as in rescaling upon browser sizing while retaining it's position).

I've tried numerous methods (HTML and CSS only), including a popular one to add the following to the CSS:

```
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
```

However this does not seem to be working for me in Chrome or Safari.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

My own code is below:

```
<div id="contentbackground">
<div id="pagecontent">
<a href="about.html">
<img src="images/frontbanner.png" alt="Click to enter" title="Click to enter" >
</a>    
</div>
</div>
```

and my CSS:

```
#contentbackground {
    background: url("../images/frontcontent.jpg");
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#pagecontent {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    padding-top: 117px;
}

#pagecontent img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your `#pagecontent` should be fixed width. Try making it `width: 100%;`
take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/dspy5xte/1/

Also, your image does not seems to be centered.

Comment: Thank you, this indeed worked.
I had given my pagecontent div the fixed width as it was advised to me that the content of a site should be designed using a 960 grid (can you tell, i'm new to this? ;) ).
I've got the image centred horizontally using margin: 0 auto, i'm working on vertical now. Thanks again

Comment: If you assign a fixed width you probably cannot make it responsive. Maybe you wanna look into media queries: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 1):

**1.)** Simply defining a `max-width` as you began should work.

```
img {
    max-width:98%;
}
```

Try cleaning up your code and defining a selector directly to your image. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eqE9J/182/).

In your specific case I would start by cleaning up by below:

```
  <img src="images/frontbanner.png" class="respondme" alt="Click to enter" title="Click to enter" >
```

---

```
.respondme { 
  max-width: 98%;
}

#pagecontent {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    padding-top: 117px;
    background: url('..coolimage.jpg'); // why do you have two wrappers, delete contentbackground entirely and merge here?
    position:relative; // adding this actually makes it a wrapper
}
```

---

**2.)** For just a **foreground image**; I prefer using [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/).

example:

```
<img src="cinqueterre.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236">
```

simply add class `.img-responsive` and your done! [**Demo**](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_img-responsive&stacked=h).

---

**3.)** For **background images**:

```
background-size: 100%;
```

Comment: See [AR_HZ's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31524142/making-an-image-responsive-re-size-with-browser#answer-31524280).  No need for Bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks for your help, though I used the above answer.

Comment: Thanks - fairly new to the site too.